# What is the difference between $http longhand and shorthand in angular 1.4.3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http

I'm trying to choose a standard for using the $http service in Angular – [longhand or shorthand/shortcut](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Is there any difference between the two for development purposes? Performance or otherwise? Or does it just come down to preference?

I prefer the longhand, I find it more readable and prefer more line breaks:

```
 $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/mydata',
    data: JSON.stringify($scope.myData),
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
 })
    .then(getReportDataComplete)
    .catch(getReportDataFailed);
```

As compared to:

```
 $http.post('api/mydata/',{
    data: JSON.stringify($scope.myData),
    headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
 })
    .then(getReportDataComplete)
    .catch(getReportDataFailed);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short Answer

They are exactly the same, you can use the one that makes you the most comfortable.

## Where is it defined?

The short functions for the $http functions are defined in [ng/http.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js).
In this file, you can find the following line:

```
createShortMethodsWithData('post', 'put', 'patch');
```

and if you look at the definition of createShortMethods, you can see:

```
function createShortMethods(names) {
  forEach(arguments, function(name) {
    $http[name] = function(url, config) {
      return $http(extend({}, config || {}, {
        method: name,
        url: url
      }));
    };
  });
}
```

The above function will go through the labels given, and set the short functions to extend the config given with the correct parameters while calling $http()